# Is there an API for the Azure Language Studio, especially for Custom Question Answering?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, nlp-question-answering, language-studio

i am currently working with the Language Studio by Azure. For now, i am wondering if there is an API for this, especially for the Custom Question Answering that i can work with on my current project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Language Studio is just a demonstrator. Everything is made thanks to APIs.

For example for Question answering: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/rest/api/cognitiveservices/questionanswering/question-answering